# How can I achieve a 30 button grid using autolayout storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

So I had this working for a 12 button (4x3) grid of buttons.

I'd like all of the buttons to be equal size, common distances above and to the side of each other, and the entire grid to be centered on the device, like so:

[image: my UI]

The problem is, it looks like a jumbled mess when I build the project.

I have no problem getting the segmented control, score, or reset buttons positioned correctly, but the grid just messes everything up.

I've been using the middle tool to set up the constraints on the grid, which worked fine for the 12 button grid:

[image: constraint editor]

However, using this only creates infinite conflicting constraints that cannot be resolved by xcode.

I am very new to iOS and could be missing something simple, but I've been trying my best to match up to the blue auto suggested lines as much as possible here.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This is not a task for interface builder. 

As Matt suggested, you should use a UICollectionView. It can do everything you're trying to do and would be simpler to set up than these layout constraints.

Alternatively, you could do this faster with a few lines of code.

Comment: Could you help me out doing it in a few lines of code? I'm trying the UICollectionView as well but I'm having some trouble setting images for them in Interface Builder

Comment: I'll post something you can try in a bit.

Comment: ermahgerd... that constraints chaos though :O

Comment: Haha, glad the community sees this as overwhelming. As a newbie I thought this just might be the way of the world for ios UI development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Instead of setting each button up in the interface builder just create the container (a `UIView`) that the whole grid should fit inside. Add `constraints` to that container for how you would want that to expand and contract with screen size.

2.) Link that container `UIView` to your .h view controller class and name it `gridContainer` or whatever.

3.) Create a property in your .h class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons;
```

4.) Then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // other stuff you're doing to set up your app
    self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

    //Do this inside the main thread to make sure all your other views are laid out before this starts
    //Sometimes when you do layout stuff before the rest of the view is set up from Interface Builder you will get weird results.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self createTwoMentionalArrayHoldingCardButtons];
        [self displayCardGrid];
    }); 


}

- (void)createTwoMentionalArrayHoldingCardButtons {
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithRowsOfButtons= [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtonsAtRowX = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
           CGRect rect = self.gridContainer.bounds;
           CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width / 6, rect.size.height / 6);
           UIButton *buttonInColumnI = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellSize.width * i, cellSize.height * x, cellSize.width, cellSize.height);
           [buttonInColumnI setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourCardImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [buttonInColumnI addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [arrayOfButtonsAtRowX addObject:buttonInColumnI];
        } 
        [arrayOfRowsOfButtons addObject:arrayOfButtonsAtRowX];
    }

    self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons = arrayWithRowsOfButtons;
}

- (void)displayCardGrid {
    for (int x = 0; x < self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons.count; x++) {
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX = self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX.count; i++) {
            UIButton *buttonAtColumnI = arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX[i];
            [self.gridContainer addSubview:buttonAtColumnI];
        }
    }
}

- (void)yourButtonAction:(UIButton *)tappedCard {
    //To swap the card image on your tapped button
    for (int x = 0; x < self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons.count; x++) {
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX = self.twoDimensionalArrayContainingRowsOfCardButtons[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX.count; i++) {
            UIButton *buttonAtColumnI = arrayOfButtonsAtColumnsAtRowX[i];
            if (tappedCard == buttonAtColumnI) {
                int row = x;
                int column = i;
                //Now you can save that the user has tapped something at this row and column.
                //While you're here, you can update the card image.
                [tappedCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CardExposedImage"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm writing this all in the box here without running it, so hopefully that works for you. Ended up being a few more lines than expected.

Edit: forgot to add that I separated the building of the card buttons and the displaying of them so that you could call the display method separately. With the property, you also have a retained source of all the cards so you can just fetch them out of the array and change what you need, as needed.

Comment: Updated a method name.

Comment: Looks pretty good... any way to add spacing between the tiles?

Comment: Two options for that, the easy one first -- just make your card images a little smaller and leave the edges transparent to give the illusion of space between the buttons. Or look at the math when creating cellSize and calculate the extra required space.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a lot simpler just to use a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and let the flow layout create the grid for you.

But even if you're not going to do that, then still, my advice is: don't set this up in Xcode / Interface Builder; make the entire grid (and constraints if you want them) in code. It's much simpler (and more fun and less boring and, of course, less error-prone).

Comment: Could you help me out doing it in a few lines of code? I'm trying the UICollectionView as well but I'm having some trouble setting images for them in Interface Builder

Comment: You don't do anything in Interface Builder. You implement the collection view data source / delegate methods, just like populating a UITableView.

Comment: I'm building a card flipping game, I want each card to show the back of the card until it is flipped. I am just starting ios and I'm on homework two of Stanfords 2013 iOS course from iTunesU. This is a homework problem. I have not learned enough in the course to do what you're suggesting. The professor seems to want us to use interface builder, as we did for the 12 card version, which was homework 1. UITableViews will be covered in lecture 17. I am on lecture 4.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. But I assure you, I've written card flipping games and I always lay out the whole thing in code. Much easier (and more fun!) than using IB. Not a collection view, but just a grid of views representing the cards.

Comment: If you want to try the collectionView route however, here's a vid showing you the basics:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-m4rHLwQ6A

Comment: I love the idea of doing it in code. the whole interface builder aspect of ios development seems like it's not real programming, it's frustrating to learn and I'd rather be coding. But everything I read online says it's a must learn for any serious ios dev.

Comment: I've also yet to find a good introduction to ios that uses code over storyboards

Comment: Autolayout and interface builder IS essential, but in my opinion meant for laying out the fundamentals of your view. Anything where repeating elements occur, you're typically better served by a tableView, collectionView, or code-generated views.

Comment: "I've also yet to find a good introduction to ios that uses code over storyboards" I'll try not to feel personally insulted by that. :)